# Unable to Cascade WMTS layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, web-mapping

I have a WMTS source in our country https://geoportal.asig.gov.al/service/wmts

I am able to create a store with that and read all the layers of WMTS service, but when i publish the layer, i can't get a layer preview, it gives me this error

[image]

I tried this in 32bit and 64 bit java environment using Tomcat as web server hosting GeoServer (2.18 and 2.21 also). I can't further use this cascaded layer anymore because of this error.

Answer (score 1):

From some quick experiments it seems that the "proxy" they have infront of their GeoServer doesn't understand how to un-urlencode a URL and thinks that the encoding is "malicious".

I've created an [enhancement request](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7195) to provide a flag to turn this behaviour off but it may be quicker to talk to the provider if you speak Albanian, and ask them to fix their proxy.

### Update

Actually on further study it seems that that the KVP path through the tile request mechanism is double encoding parts of the URL.